# Using preprocessing function with identifier parser in FParsec?

Tags: parsing, f#, fparsec

I am using the `identifier` parser from FParsec to parse the names of variables and functions, which are normally a mixture of Unicode and ASCII characters. But sometimes I have escaped Unicode characters in the beginning (like `\u03C0`) or within the identifier (like `swipe_board\u003A_b`). I still can make them parseable using `isAsciiIdStart` and `isAsciiIdContinue` options, but I can't define my own custom function for pre-processing before normalization. What could be a solution here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `identifier` parser internally first parses a string and then passes it to an `IdentifierValidator` instance for validation. Since the C# `IdentifierValidator` class is publicly accessible (though not documented), you could easily adapt the `identifier` parser to your needs (by making the initial string parsing step also recognize the escapes).

The identifier parsing is a bit complicated due to support for UTF-16 surrogate pairs, normalization and the Unicode XID character category, which is not natively supported on .NET.
Maybe you only need to support ASCII or UCS-2 identifiers specified in term of character categories supported by `CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory`, in which case you could probably implement the parsing and validation in just one step using `many1Satisfy2` or `many1Chars2`.